# asp.net mvc - Trying to have a partial view in my layout and getting:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use a partial view through a controller in my layout like so:

**`_Layout.cshtml`**:

```
<ul id="menu">
     <li>@Html.Action("Menu")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

**`MenuController.cs`**:

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Menu/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var menu = new Models.Menu()
        {
            Items = new List<Models.MenuItem>()
            {
                new Models.BaseMenuBtn() { Label = "One", Link= "Home", CssClass="a"},
                new Models.BaseMenuBtn() { Label = "One", Link= "Home", CssClass="b"}
            }
        };

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Models**:

**`Menu.cs`**:

```
public class Menu : MenuItem
{
   public List<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }

   public override string Render()
   {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<div>");

       foreach (var item in Items)
       {
           sb.Append(item.Render());
       }

       sb.Append("</div>");

       return sb.ToString();
   }

   public Menu()
   {
       Items = new List<Models.MenuItem>()
            {
                new Models.BaseMenuBtn() { Label = "One", Link= "Home", CssClass="a"},
                new Models.BaseMenuBtn() { Label = "One", Link= "Home", CssClass="b"}
            };


   }
}
```

**`MenuItem.cs`**:

```
    public abstract class MenuItem
{
    public string CssClass { get; set; }

    public abstract string Render();
}
```

**`BaseMenuBtn.cs`**

```
public class BaseMenuBtn : MenuItem
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }

    public override string Render()
    {
        return string.Format("<div href='{0}' class='{1}'> {2} </div>", this.Link , this.CssClass, this.Label);
    }
}
```

And, from the line I added in the layout, I'm getting this error:

> Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Please help.

Comment: The idea of `mvc` pattern is to separate coding and mark-up. So having html in models is bad practice. I have not done much with `asp.net mvc` but generally this is breaking mvc pattern, IMO.

Comment: Where is your `Index.cshtml` for the `Menu` controller?

Comment: You're right, and I'm doing this only to see this work for the first time before I put everything in place.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to generate HTML from a model, you really should be creating an extension to the `HtmlHelper` class. For instance, I created this for a site nav extension:

```
public static HtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string text, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues)
{
    string currentAction = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    string currentController = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");

    var li = new TagBuilder("li");

    if (actionName.ToLower() == currentAction.ToLower() && controllerName.ToLower() == currentController.ToLower())
    {
        li.AddCssClass("selected");
    }

    li.InnerHtml = helper.ActionLink(linkText: text, actionName: actionName, controllerName: controllerName, routeValues: routeValues, htmlAttributes: null).ToHtmlString();

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
}
```

Once I register the namespace of my extensions in the `web.config` files, I can call this helper like so:

```
@Html.MenuLink("Contact", "contact", "home", new { })
```

which generates this for me:

```
<li class="selected">
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
</li>
```

You should be able to follow this pattern and adjust the code above to fit your needs; if not, ask and I'll see if I can come up with a simple/naive example.